# Is there an R implementation of imagemagicks "+level-colors"?

Tags: r, imagemagick

I'd like to do the equivalent Image Magick process in R using `library(magick)`:

```
convert 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/jpg/surf.jpg' +level-colors green,white output.jpg
```

It essentially maps the colors 'black' and 'white' to the given colors (green/white) -- with a nice gradient.

Here's as close as I've come in R:

```
library(magick)

input <- image_read("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/jpg/surf.jpg")

input %>%
    image_transparent("#000", fuzz = 50) %>%
    image_background("green")
```

The input image is below, followed by the preferred output, followed by the poor R output.

## Input

[image]

## Preferred (generated by command line imagemagick 7)

[image]

## Output of R

[image]

Comment: I do not know RMagick, but you could create a green-white gradient. Then use that with the R equivalent of -clut.

Comment: Yes, that's a great alternative, but I don't see -clut in the R library. I'm specifically looking for an R implementation -- even if not in imagemagick.

Comment: See https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#clut_channel or https://rmagick.github.io/image2.html#level_colors

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion...there is a Ruby version of image magick. However, I'm looking for the R version. R as in the letter: https://www.r-project.org/.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did not know there was a difference.

Answer (score 1):

## Cheating

### Pro

It gets you exactly what you want, and it's inside R.

### Con

It doesn't show the image-processing details, which you might want to see.

```
# --- Use system call

# For example: ls, invoked from R
# list_of_files <- system( "ls -F", intern = TRUE )

# --- Put your Magick script here
CMD <- "convert 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/jpg/surf.jpg' +level-colors green,white output.jpg"

# --- Then invoke it, returning the result to R
colorized_image <- system( CMD, intern = TRUE )
```

## Using package `imager`

```
# --- Libraries
require( imager )
require( purrr )

# --- Configuration
PATH <- 'path/to/image/file'
TEST_IMAGE <- "people.png"
RED  <- 1
GRN  <- 2
BLU  <- 3

# --- Adjustments you can make:
white_threshold <- 0.85
haziness <-  white_threshold
how_much_haze <- 0.67

# --- Load the image
m <- load.image( file.path( PATH, TEST_IMAGE ))

# --- Convert to Cimg format
m <- as.cimg( m[,,,1:3] )

# --- Extract each color channel
red <- R( m )
grn <- G( m )
blu <- B( m )

# --- Make a grayscale version
g <- grayscale( m )

# --- Remember which pixels are white[st]
#     ( to capture more white, lower the threshold )
wht <- threshold( g, white_threshold )
px <- m >= white_threshold

# Drop flat dimensions ( there is only one frame, so we drop that dimension)
dmg <- as.data.frame(  m, drop = TRUE )

# --- below white_threshold, change color to green
dmg[ dmg$value < white_threshold, 'cc' ] <- GRN

# --- white_threshold and above, change color to white
dmg[ dmg$value >= white_threshold, 'value' ] <- 1.0

# --- blend the green-i-fied image with haze
#     NOTE: This isn't what Magick +level-colors does
#           Instead, it's a crude approximation.
haze <- as.cimg ( dmg )
R( haze ) <- haziness
G( haze ) <- haziness
B( haze ) <- haziness

# --- Make an image-list, then compute the weighted-sum
imgs <- as.imlist( list( as.cimg( dmg ), haze ))
hazy <- wsum( imgs, c( 1 - how_much_haze, how_much_haze ))

plot( hazy, rescale = FALSE, axes = FALSE )
```

[image: Tinted image]

## A note about `plot( rescale = FALSE )`

The `plot()` function will automatically rescale color values by default, unless you tell it not to. If you plot without rescaling, you can see the effects from the processing, above. *However*, you must ensure the RGB color values are in the range [0,1]. Otherwise, you will see this:

Error in colourscale(v[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmb41.png)], v[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmb41.png)], v[[3]]) :
color intensity -0.494265, not in [0,1]

If you plot *with* rescaling, it will obscure the effects.

## Bonus Functions

```
# These HSV functions can cause color values to be outside the range [0,1]
# See the note about `plot( rescale = FALSE )`, above.

# a function to Convert to HSV,  reduce saturation,  convert back
reduce_saturation <- function( im, k = 0.5 ){
  RGBtoHSV( im ) %>%
    imsplit( "c" ) %>%
      modify_at( 2, ~ . * k ) %>%
        imappend( "c" ) %>%
          HSVtoRGB
}

shift_hue <- function( im, k = 0.75 ){
  RGBtoHSV( im ) %>%
    imsplit( "c" ) %>%
      modify_at( 1, ~ . * k ) %>%
        imappend( "c" ) %>%
          HSVtoRGB
}

reduce_intensity <- function( im, k = 0.5 ){
  RGBtoHSV( im ) %>%
    imsplit( "c" ) %>%
      modify_at( 3, ~ . * k ) %>%
        imappend( "c" ) %>%
          HSVtoRGB
}
```

Demonstration

```
# layout((1:2))
# hazy %>% plot( rescale = FALSE, axes = FALSE )
# reduce_saturation( hazy, 0.7 ) %>% plot( rescale = FALSE, axes = FALSE )
```

[image: example tinted images]

Comment: I get an error with your `m <- as.cimg( m[,,,1:3] )`: "Error in `[.default`(m, , , , 1:3) : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Immediatly after `m <- load.image( file.path( PATH, TEST_IMAGE ))` what size/shape is m? `dim( m )` on my machine shows `[ 640 480   1   4 ]`; and what class of object is it? `class(m)
[1] "cimg"         "imager_array" "numeric"  `     `as.cimg( m[,,,1:3] )` just strips off the 4th slice of the fourth dimension.  Can you skip the `as.cimg` and simply get green channel using `G( m )`?

Comment: `dim(m)` produces: "640 480   1   1". `class(m)` produces '"cimg"         "imager_array" "numeric"'. I can't get G(m), because that leads to "Error in `[.default`(im, , , , ind, drop = FALSE) : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Comment: I got the your example to work with a different image file, a png. Hmm.